# iText 7 and form field value with diacritics

Tags: java, itext, diacritics, itext7

I have a working solution in iText 5 where I fill in form fields like this:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setField("city", "ěščřžýáíéĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ");
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```

And the correct result is:
[image: iText 5 form field value]

---

But after upgrade on iText 7 diacritics stopped to work.

```
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(document, true);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
PdfFormField field = fields.get("city");
field.setValue("ěščřžýáíéĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ");
form.flattenFields();
```

Now the result is incorrect: [image: iText 7 form field value]

I tried different versions of iText libraries (7.0.4 and 7.1.2) and then I tried to convert values into different encoding (windows-1250 and iso-8859-2) but nothing helped.

**Update:** Next approach works but it is not the correct replacement of the iText 5 functionality because here I'm changing font and text size of the field and I should not care about it when I'm only filling in the form, moreover when fields have different font family, weight and size:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA, PdfEncodings.CP1250, true);
field.setValue("ěščřžýáíéĚŠČŘŽÝÁÍÉ", font, 10f);
```

Is there anything else to do in iText 7 to have values correctly filled in form fields?

Thank you